# kotlin plugin not found Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.8.20', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.8.20', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.8.20')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Google
  MavenRepo
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:238)

The build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```

The setting.gradle file:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

I changed the kotlin version, it doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't use any gradle-legacy methods such as "apply" in your files. Remove it and try again

Comment: I solved it by adding my cert.
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mcafreeroot -file "{my_cert.crt}" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\lib\security\cacerts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding my cert.
**keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mcafreeroot -file "{my_cert.crt}" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\lib\security\cacerts"**